# How to correctly calculate forward and backward percentage in Java by BigDecimal?

Tags: java, percentage, bigdecimal

There is mismatch between two results, which are got when I try to calculate percentage having initial summa (let's say - forward commission) and adjusted summa (let's call this backward commission).

So let me have 25 as initial value.

I'd like to calculate 3.5%.

What am I doing for this?

```
P = 25 - 25*(1-3.5/100) = 0.875.
```

In terms of Java it looks like this

where initValue equals `25` for sure, and percent equals `3.5`

```
    initValue.subtract(initValue.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(percent.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

**result = 0.87** given by Java

Let me substract this from 25. My final result is 24.13.

So let's assume that I need to calculate backward commission from this summa 24.13

24.13/(1 - 3.5/100)

and this gives me **0.88** when I use Google Sheet and the following Java code:

```
updatedValue.divide(BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(percent.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2)), RoundingMode.HALF_UP).subtract(updatedValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

where updatedValue equals 24.13 and percent still 3.5

Basically since mathematical context seems to me as doubtless should I expect that my backward commission give me 0.87 ? And why I get 0.88 constantly then ?

Comment: Rounding error - You are forcing results to be calculated to 2 decimal places, losing precision.

Comment: But since I calculate money value - any ideas how to get the same commission ?

Comment: Ask a (legal/financial) professional in the topic how the roundings are supposed to work in your country in these type of scenarios. Here in Mexico, for example, we have a tax that should be 2/3 of the price, which IS VERY PRONE to rounding errors. As such, the tributary system decided that the calculations should be with a precision of 5 decimals and then rounded to 2 decimals. I doubt your tributary entity doesn't have a ruling for that.

Answer (score 0):

In java.math RoundingMode.HALF_UP means "Rounding mode to round towards nearest neighbor unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up". Since you are calculating money I recommend you to make the rounding operations at the end of the calculation.

```
initValue.subtract(initValue.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(percent.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2))).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

This will actually give you the same result **0,87**.

When you calculate the backward commission it is best to change the rounding mode since it is a backward operation. So the code will be:

```
updatedValue.divide(BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(percent.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2)), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).subtract(updatedValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```

This will give you the same result **0,87**.